# Undeclared identifier with definition in header file

Tags: c, pointers, interpreter, lexer, undeclared-identifier

include "spinach.h" is included in the main.c file

main.c makes a function call to a struct defined in spinach.h header. The function call occurs in the main.c function, and is the first reference to this type Lexer. The main.c file runs without error absent this line.

```
  Lexer *lex = malloc(sizeof(Lexer));
```

The definition is on the 0 indentation level (it is not defined in local scope); it is given below in triple quotes. In the header (spinach.h)

```
typedef struct {
  char **lines;
  char* current;
  int pos;
  int line;
  int col;

  int* indentlevel;
  int indentcap;
  int indentlen;
} Lexer;
```

What happpens?

```
 bash run.sh
main.c:115:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Lexer'
  Lexer *lex;
  ^
main.c:115:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'lex'
  Lexer *lex;
         ^
2 errors generated.
```

Any variation that includes Lexer, including using pointers, references to malloc or the output of a custom initializer function will throw related errors.

Looked for multiple references (same global variable in 2 files in *main.py* references) to Lexer. All references on the internet are examples wherein the header file is not included, the variable or function is defined after the reference or call, or is absent entirely, else the error will show where there shows a reference in a global scope to a local definition. I do not see this to be the case. All references to custom struct lever in the main.c file, main function will throw this error. If the definitions are placed in the main.c file itself, instead of the header spinach.h referenced, it runs without error.

Comment: You haven't shown us enough code to see what the problem is.  Describing the code doesn't help. Please update your question to include a [mcve] that others can compile as is to get the same error you do.

Comment: Perhaps you haven't saved spinich.h to disk, so the include is picking up an older version without the definition. That has happened for other questions posted here in the past. Next possibility: you have another spinach.h file and the wrong one is in the directory the compiler is searching in. That has also happened to people.

Comment: Reduce the problem to a [mre]: Copy your directory for this project to a new directory where you can edit it with abandon. Remove everything from `spinach.h` except the definition of the `Lexer` type. Remove everything from `main.c` except the `#include` directive for `"spinach.h"` and `int main(void) { Lexer *lex = malloc(sizeof(Lexer)); }`. Then execute `run.sh`. If the error occurs then, execute `gcc -E main.c >x.txt` and edit the contents of `x.txt` into the question. (If you are not using GCC, state what compiler you are using.)…

Comment: … If the error does not occur after the above reduction, something else was causing the problem. Restore the files and then experiment with removing various parts of `spinach.h` and `main.c` to see which part causes the problem. Once you have reduced it to a [mre], the problem may be obvious. If it is not, then edit the [mre] into the question.